# running rsync in cygwin

Tags: powershell, path, cygwin, whitespace, rsync

I am trying to run rsync from cygwin in a PowerShell script of a remote folder with having space (File - One) and gets the below error. Tried to escape the space but still it does not work. As in the error, the directory name taken is "/e/Files/File" which is incomplete, whereas the actual folder name should be "/e/Files/File - One/root/" . Also tried the escape the space with multiple backslashes but still same error. What could be issue here?

```
Write-Output $rsync-cmd

Invoke-Expression -command $rsync_cmd
```

Command and Error:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login -c 'rsync -tvhPrI --stats jason@10.1.1.100:"/e/Files/File\ -\ One/root/" "/e/Files/File\ -\ One/root"'

receiving incremental file list
rsync: link_stat "/e/Files/File" failed: No such file or directory (2)

rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1637) [Receiver=3.1.1]
```

Comment: escape the destination string in the same way you escaped the first one: `"/e/Files/File\\ -\\ One/root"` - alternatively just a single backslash to escape

Comment: Yes, i have tried that too.. it doesn't work and have the same error.

Comment: just updated the script, so it there is no confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been wrestling with this and all problems solved by running my script through dos2unix to remove rogue ^M